# php upload textarea content into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

i have html/php code with form standard desing that includes textarea item. i can't find the way to add textarea content to a table in mysql database.

html/php

```
<form action="this_file.php" method="POST">
    <textarea class="inputcat" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="upload text" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
//allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
session_start();
//connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $con) or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //insert the row into the database
        $contenido = $_POST['content'];
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`ct`) VALUE('" .$contenido. "')"; // syntax corrected here
        $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

    }
?>
```

thank you very much.

greetings.

Comment: Corrected your syntax error ... does the above work for you now?

Comment: no it's not. i'll see slowly much better. i'll tell you somthing.

Comment: there should be another " before the semi-colon on the $SQL line - it is missing above, I tried editing it about an hour ago but the edit wasn't put it place - I've tried again but this is a note to say where the correction should go

Comment: i dont understand your answer

Comment: `$SQL = "INSERT INTO 'table1' ('ct') VALUE('" .$contenido. "')";` ... also, did you try `print_r($_POST);` to see what is being sent through??

Comment: it returnes: Array ( [content] => text test. [submit] => upload text )

Comment: So it's all going in correctly, are there any errors appearing or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: dont write content to the table !!! it's unreal !! :( i used  this line: $SQL = "INSERT INTO ``table1`` (``ct``) VALUE('" .$contenido. "')";

Comment: you could always try changing the following line (`mysql_query($SQL)`) to `mysql_query($SQL, $con)` but unlikely to make a difference. I'm surprised mysql_error isn't popping anything out. My try echoing $contenido after it is populated from $_POST['content'] but before the $SQL line, then do the same after the line with $result in it - then see in the browser how many times the content appears...

Comment: sorry i have not seen that error in print_r($_POST) . this is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7591/discussion-between-mrj-and-raphael-d-g)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try changing:

```
<form>
```

To:

```
<form action="name_of_this_file.php" method="post">
```

Nothing else really springs to mind from what I can see...

You could always do:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

At the very top to see what exactly is coming into the page upon submit....

Comment: Deleted my answer, as this basically answers the question, and a little better too.

Answer (score 0):

Also change your query line to this, there is a syntax error in your code:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`ct`) VALUE ('$contenido')";
```

Consider looking at escaping data before inserting it into the database, more information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

**Edit:**
Maybe you should also look at how you debug PHP: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/ - This will definitely save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: Yep - just to echo the above, make sure you sanitize data input - we don't want any nasty SQL injections now!